# SQL - How to exclude Sunday from date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code

```
SELECT AccountNum, DateStart, DateEnd
FROM TableA
WHERE DateStart > '2020-04-01'
AND DateStart => DATEADD(day,-5, DateEnd)
```

The code currently grabs all the records where the DateEnd is within 5 days of DateStart.

What I want to add is for it to exclude Sunday as one of the days it counts. So if Sunday happens to be one of the days between DateEnd and DateEnd - 5 then change that -5 to a -6.

Answer (score 2):

Sunday is going to be one of the days on all days except Friday or Saturday.  Assuming you are using English language settings:

```
WHERE DateStart > '2020-04-01' AND
      (DateStart >= DATEADD(day, -5, DateEnd) OR
      (DATENAME(weekday, DateStart) NOT IN ('Friday', 'Saturday') AND
       DateStart >= DATEADD(day, -6, DateEnd) 
      )
```

Comment: Im not understanding why you are putting in NOT IN Friday or Saturday. Could you explain that part alittle bit more?

Comment: @pcct2020 . . . Because based on your rules, you need to subtract 5 days on Friday and Saturday and 6 days on any other day.